# Search in specific Index Name by SearchRequest in Nest v7.10.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have 2 indexes in the same server with the same struct and different index names.
The 1st is for dev reasons and the 2nd for uat reasons.
I have both index names in appsettings and the program uses the appropriate depends the environment.
I want to declare in searchRequest the index name but in Nest v7.10.0 searchRequest doesn't have Indices.

```
            ISearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
            {
                From = query.Payload.Paging?.Skip,
                Size = query.Payload.Paging?.Take ?? 10000,
                Sort = sortField != null ? new List<ISort> { sortField } : null,
                Query = new QueryContainer(boolQuery),
                Source = new SourceFilter
                {
                    Includes = Infer.Field<EventHistory>(path: eventHistory => eventHistory.Id)
                }
            };

            ISearchResponse<EventHistory> searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EventHistory>(searchRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor takes an `Indices` argument

```cs
ISearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("foo")
{
    
    From = query.Payload.Paging?.Skip,
    Size = query.Payload.Paging?.Take ?? 10000,
    Sort = sortField != null ? new List<ISort> { sortField } : null,
    Query = new QueryContainer(boolQuery),
    Source = new SourceFilter
    {
        Includes = Infer.Field<EventHistory>(path: eventHistory => eventHistory.Id)
    }
};

ISearchResponse<EventHistory> searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<EventHistory>(searchRequest);
```